# Existe algum evento que capture mundanças de tamanho de um elemento HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber se existe algum evento que capte mudanças de tamanho de um elemento HTML. Por exemplo, uma *div* com *5000px* de altura passa a ter *4800px* e o `onresize()` do Javascript não dispara.

Existe algum evento que capture isso?

HTML:

```
<div id="teste" style="height:1500px; background:#F00"></div>
```

JS:

```
// Evento que vai captura a mudança na altura dp documento
window.onresize = function(){
    alert('mudança na altura do documento');
}
// Diminui o div para disparar o evento
setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById('teste').style.height = '300px' 
}, 3000);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/71dygzcd/2/)

Notem que a altura do documento é alterada mas o evento de `resize` não dispara.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Como assim o `onresize` não funciona? Pode postar o que já testou?

Comment: Então é que quero capturar a mudança de altura do documento e não da janela.... Postei o codigo de teste no corpo da pergunta. Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Douglas efectivamente só o `window` é que gera esse evento `resize`. Para capturar mudanças em elementos tem de usar `setInterval` e isso pode atrasar muito a performance. Então a minha pergunta é: o que quer fazer mesmo, o que faz essa mudança de tamanho acontecer? Acho que pode estar a tentar resolver o problema no sitio errado.

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

um workaround:

```js
var elemento = $("#teste");
var onResize = function() {
  elemento.css("background-color", "green");
  console.log("RESIZE!!");
};


elemento.data("size", {
  width: elemento[0].offsetWidth,
  height: elemento[0].offsetHeight
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (elemento.data("size").width != elemento[0].offsetWidth || elemento.data("size").height != elemento[0].offsetHeight) {
    onResize();
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);



setTimeout(function() {
  elemento.css("width", "300px");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste" style="width: 200px;height:200px;background-color: red;">
  <div>
```

Comment: Neste exemplo, o quando o elemento for alterado, o método onResize será chamado, e o "listener" será limpo.

Answer (score 0):

[ATUALIZADO] JavaScript:

```
$('#test_div').bind('resize', function(){
            console.log('resized');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   $('#test_div').resize();
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/sgsqJ/4/

Comment: E ai cara blz? Então não é isso que preciso(altera a estilo do elemento), preciso capturar a mudança de tamanho do documento( document.body.clientHeight ), mas valew

Comment: Deculpa! Atualizei!

Comment: Valeu, mas é que o resize não captura a mudança de altura do documento( lembrando estou falando de documento não janela), mas valeu

*Adicionei o codigo de teste na pergunta se quiser dar uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Também é possível descobrir quando muda o tamanho com CSS3.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 4800px) and (max-width: 5000px) { 
  background-color:red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 4800px) { background-color:blue; }
```

Comment: Valeu cara mas com media queries não tenho callback por isso que necessito do javascript.... valeu

Answer (score 0):

Pode dar uma olhada em http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

Ele faz disparar o evento resize, porém é provável que ele dispare somente utilizando os handlers que ele disponibiliza.

um exemplo:

```
$( "#teste" ).resizable({ 
    resize: function(e,ui) { 
        console.log("deu resize!") 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo com o código fonte?

Comment: $( "#teste" ).resizable({
  resize: function(e,ui) { console.log("deu resize!") }
});

Comment: mas infelizmente o resize é disparado quando você dá um drag nos handlers. 
ou seja, se alterar o style width, não será disparado.